# how to connect directional sub-graphs in R igraph

Tags: r, connection, igraph, shortest-path

I have a directional weighted graph that is made of two *or more* disconnected sub-graphs (with some attributes, in addition to `weight`):

```
require(igraph)
df<-data.frame(from=c(1,2,4,5),to=c(2,3,5,6),weight=c(1,1,1,1),attr=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1))
g<-graph_from_data_frame(df,directed=T)
```

My ultimate goal is to find shortest path, but this can be done only for connected graphs.

As a result, I need to connect these two sub-graphs with an edge between 3 and 4 with the large weight (perhaps `vcount(g)`) so at the end I have just one graph. In general, vertex names are dates that define direction (from smaller to larger). More than one gap can be present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the code below if you have more than one gap (i.e., more than two clusters)

```
e <- c(sapply(decompose(g),function(x) names(V(x))[degree(x)==1]))
G <- g %>% 
  add.edges(e[2:(length(e)-1)],weight = vcount(g))
```

such that

```
> get.data.frame(G)
  from to weight attr
1    1  2      1  0.1
2    2  3      1  0.1
3    4  5      1  0.1
4    5  6      1  0.1
5    7  8      1  0.1
6    8  9      1  0.1
7    3  4      9   NA
8    6  7      9   NA
```

**Data**

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    from = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8),
    to = c(2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9),
    weight = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    attr = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, I just modified one line because the degree is usually not equal to one for my graphs: `e<-c(sapply(decompose(g),function(x) names(V(x))[c(1,length(V(x)))]))`

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you could do:
(Thanks for the comment by [@ThomasIsCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67130994/how-to-connect-directional-sub-graphs-in-r-igraph/67131492?noredirect=1#comment118661935_67131492)

```
h <- add.edges(g, c("3","4"), weight = vcount(g))
```

Comment: we can put `weight = vcount(g)` in `add.edges` as well.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me to understand how to add an edge.